# Rails find_each is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku, clockwork

Currently, I'm triggering a SuckerPunch Job via clockwork in my Rails app.

```
User.find_each do |user|
    puts "Found user: #{user.name}!"
end

# Doesn't work, too.
User.all.each do |user|
    puts "Found user: #{user.name}!"
end
```

However, the execution stucks when searching for the users. When printing the `Enumerator` (`User.find_each.inspect`) to the console it shows the users. Why won't the block run? May there be a Rails context missing?

It's been driving me crazy for hours. I'm deploying to Heroku, btw.

EDIT: I figured out, there's an error: `Primary key not included in the custom select clause`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're hitting some sort of limit due to the number of Users in the db. Have you tried using find_in_batch instead?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each (uses find_in_batch with a default batch_size of 1000)
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches (note the last post)

Comment: I tried using find_in_batch instead but it produced the same error. There are only two users in the database.

Comment: How are you executing the code, and what is the result? Is it just the Primary Key error?

Comment: It's just that error. I suspect there's something from with my schema/model so I adjusted some things. Users.all.each is working now - will try Users.find_each tomorrow.